# Understanding Gnome various Icons

Tags: fedora, gnome3, icons

The question is about customizing the way icon appears at

1. desktop shell
2. notification area
3. file associations

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Version=1.0
   Type=Application
   Name=Mathematica 9
   Comment=Technical Computing System
   Exec=/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/Executables/Mathematica %F
   Icon=wolfram-mathematica
   MimeType=application/mathematica;application/vnd.wolfram.cdf
   Categories=Education
   ```

Now provided I can make a custom desktop file where I can place png file location at icon...but how come the above desktop file is referring to an icon & where is that icon (wolfram-mathematica)?

Secondly how to system wide change icon of a special file type say a docx to something else 
[image]

Third & last how gnome load tray icons & where are those icons stored e.g I want to customise autokey tray icon to something else how can I do it? Have also looked at /usr/share/pixmaps but to no avail

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, desktop files aka "launchers" (should) comply to [freedesktop specs](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-1.0.html). As to the icon, the above specification explains:

> Icon to display in file manager, menus, etc. If the name is an
> absolute path, the given file will be used. If the name is not an
> absolute path, the algorithm described in the [Icon Theme Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/icon-theme-spec/icon-theme-spec-latest.html)
> will be used to locate the icon.

the algorithm being:

> Icons and themes are looked for in a set of directories. By default,
> apps should look in $HOME/.icons (for backwards compatibility), in
> $XDG_DATA_DIRS/icons and in /usr/share/pixmaps (in that order).
>
> ........................................................................
>
> The icon lookup mechanism has two global settings, the list of base
> directories and the internal name of the current theme. Given these we
> need to specify how to look up an icon file from the icon name and the
> nominal size.
>
> The lookup is done first in the current theme, and then recursively in
> each of the current theme's parents, and finally in the default theme
> called "hicolor" (implementations may add more default themes before
> "hicolor", but "hicolor" must be last). As soon as there is an icon of
> any size that matches in a theme, the search is stopped. Even if there
> may be an icon with a size closer to the correct one in an inherited
> theme, we don't want to use it. Doing so may generate an inconsistant
> change in an icon when you change icon sizes (e.g. zoom in). The
> lookup inside a theme is done in three phases. First all the
> directories are scanned for an exact match, e.g. one where the allowed
> size of the icon files match what was looked up. Then all the
> directories are scanned for any icon that matches the name. If that
> fails we finally fall back on unthemed icons. If we fail to find any
> icon at all it is up to the application to pick a good fallback, as
> the correct choice depends on the context.

As per the above, on most modern desktops, icon themes location is `$XDG_DATA_DIRS/icons`, that is `/usr/share/icons` (global) and `~./local/share/icons` (user).

---

Second, changing an icon for a file type system-wide involves changing the mimetype icon coresponding to that file mime type, i.e. for `.docx` files the mime type is

```
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
```

Gnome default icon set has no icon for that specific mime type so it falls back to `x-office-document` (full path being `/usr/share/icons/gnome/$SIZE/mimetypes/x-office-document`). Changing the icon for `.docx` means you either have to come up with a new icon (of various sizes) named

```
application-vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document.png
```

or replace the `x-office-document.png` that is used by default. Note the latter will change the icon for all files associated with `x-office-document` mime type, not only `.docx`.

It is not recommended to alter icon themes in `/usr/share/icons` as your changes will most likely be overwritten by future updates so your best bet is to place your favorite icon theme in `~./local/share/icons` and add/modify whatever you want.

---

Finally, identifying the tray icons used by Gnome is not a trivial task, see this on [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153222/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-what-is-the-name-of-an-icon-that-is-on-the-bottom-bar). Not sure if it applies to Gnome 3.6 since some shell parts are still under major rearchitecture and code changes every release.